# Elevate PSFTP "put" command as root

Tags: linux, sudo, putty

Attempting to use PSFTP to "put" a file from my local Windows 7 machine up to a directory on a remote Ubuntu server with only root access permitted. How do I sudo elevate my PSFTP session to execute the put as root?

The following for i.e. is not supported:

```
sudo put test.xml
```

In my preliminary research, it seems the only alternative, which I'd like to shortcut, is to put to my home directory and then mv to the final location via SSH (where I can sudo mv). Or of course logging in as root in the first place which is not at all a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible which is understandable, but unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't elevate your windows session to allow the put, you provide root's credentials when connecting to the remote machine

```
psftp root@remote.tld 
Using Username root
root@remote.tld's password:
Remote Working directory is /root
psftp>
```

Now you can navigate around the remote filesystem and `put` your file wherever yo want. If it's just a single file to a particular remote directory then you could use pscp

```
pscp yourfile.ext root@remote.tld:/path/to/save
```

Have a look at the relevant man pages - psftp implements [**sftp**](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sftp&sektion=1) and pscp implements [**scp**](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1)

Comment: Iain, thanks for the response. However, "Or of course logging in as root in the first place which is not at all a viable alternative."

Comment: Aside from the fact that we're working with Ubuntu...so root@remote.tld account never enabled in the first place. All root actions done with sudo or su - for a root shell. Was hoping would have the same possibility with psftp.

Comment: Your question also says `with only root access permitted` so which is it ?

Comment: Directory in question permissions are root root. Therefore do not want to login with root account, but rather, elevate as necessary so that write privileges to directory/files belonging to root. That more clear?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, PSFTP'ing with account that is in sudoers list.